# Search brings up deleted questions in results

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, search

Couple of days ago I started noticing deleted questions appearing in search results. At first I thought it was mod vision (moderators can search for deleted posts) but today when I happened to search in <strike>porn</strike> incognito mode:

[image]

The [circled question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181462/how-to-connect-ios-application-to-a-telephone-system-through-gprs-and-getting-ph)<sup>10K+ link</sup> was deleted on February 9 and it really shouldn't be in the search results.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same phenomenon too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bad shard was in play here with 12,230 bad documents...well not necessarily bad, but some aged and didn't update afterwards due to an ID mismatch on the mapping.  The offending shard  and replica has been nuked from existence and the content re-indexed.  Searches should no longer contain deleted content.